# print list with values closest to inputted value Python

Tags: python

I have wrote a code that prints "range" number of lists. But I want to change the code, so that it prints only list , where values are bigger than 1.
Can you help me with it?

[image]

```
x=int(input("enter: "))
y=int(input("enter: "))`
for i in range (x,y):`
    A=i*0.16
    B=i*0.14

lista=[]
lista.append(A)
lista.append(B)

print(lista)
```

Comment: What exactly would be the desired output here

Comment: Your question title and question body seem to be asking completely different things. Do you want the values closest to some value, or do you want all values that are larger than 1?

Comment: It is not clear, what you ask here, but you can find the closest element of an ordered list with `bisect`: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/bisect.html

Comment: I edited the question, so added the picture. I hope that the question is clearer now. Sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: So you want to have only the first tuple, where both values are larger than 1?

Comment: yes. Only one where both values are larger then 1

Comment: What should happen, if no pair has both values larger than 1?

Comment: It should print the tuple that has the closest value to 1

Answer (score 0):

This should do, what you are looking for. You don't need a loop for that. Actually `x` doesn't influence the result at all.

```
x=int(input("enter: "))
y=int(input("enter: "))

z = int(1 / 0.14) + 1

if z <= y:
    a = (0.16 * z, 0.14 * z)
else:
    a = (0.16 * y, 0.14 * y)
```

I genuinely fail to see, why you need a loop for this task, but here we go:

```
x=int(input("enter: "))
y=int(input("enter: "))

for i in range(x, y):
    A = 0.16 * i
    B = 0.14 * i
    if A >=1 and B >=1:
        a = (A, B)
        break
else:
    a = (0.16 * y, 0.14 * y)

print(a)
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it with loop? I did this:

`x=int(input("enter 1: "))`
`y=int(input("enter 2: "))`

`for i in range (x,y):`
        
   `A=i*0.1316`
    `B=i*0.1463`

    `lista=[]`
 
    `lista.append(A)`
    `lista.append(B)`
    
    `if A>=1 and B>=1:`
        `print("for",i,"days: ",lista)`

Now It prints only tuples that are bigger than 1, but I do not know how to set it to print the tuple thats closest to 1 (first tuple)

Comment: I updated the entry with a `for - else` loop approach. But I wouldn't use it, given your information.